# prepareForSegue Not Being Called upon Peeking

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

I'm trying to implement peek and pop support for a static Table View. I was successful at getting peek and pop to actually work, but prepareForSegue is not being called when peeking on a cell.

```
//  MasterPreviewing.swift
import UIKit

extension ThemesViewController: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {
func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThemesPreviewStoryboard") as? ThemePreviewViewController else { return nil }

    viewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 376, height: 668)

    return viewController
  }

func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commitViewController viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
    showViewController(viewControllerToCommit, sender: self)
  }
}
```

-

```
// ThemesViewController.swift
import UIKit
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for cell in cells {
        if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .Available {
            self.registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(self, sourceView: cell)
        }
    }

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    print("prepareForSegue called")

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You aren't performing a segue, so why would `prepareForSegue` b called?

Comment: Before I switched over to doing this programatically, I was enabling Peek and Pop directly from the storyboards. Turns out prepareForSegue is only called when you enable Peek and Pop through storyboards. @Paulw11

Comment: That's correct, because then you are using a peek segue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out prepareForSegue is only called when setting up Peek and Pop using storyboards. I put my code in `MasterPreviewing.swift`, and all seems good now!